# How can I reload views after choose dark mode?

Tags: ios, swift

Im using this pod for add dark mode to my app. 
https://github.com/draveness/NightNight

Its working well when I restart app again but I want to change theme inside of app. So, I added UISwitch to my sidepanel for user can change theme.

I added this codes for it and some colors changing well but some colors does not affect. For example NavigationBar background color is changing well but title color is not changing.

UISwitch Action:

```
@IBAction func switchMode(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        if sender.isOn {
            switcher.isOn =  true

                NightNight.theme = NightNight.Theme.night
                UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#141d27")
                UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
                UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#6e00ff")
                UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#6e00ff")
                UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
                UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#141d27")


            for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
                for view in window.subviews {
                    view.removeFromSuperview()
                    window.addSubview(view)
                }
            }

                UserDefaults.standard.set("night", forKey: "colormode")



        } else {
            switcher.isOn =  false

            NightNight.theme = NightNight.Theme.normal
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
            UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
            UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#6e00ff")
            UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#6e00ff")
            UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
            UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white

            for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
                for view in window.subviews {
                    view.removeFromSuperview()
                    window.addSubview(view)
                }
            }

            UserDefaults.standard.set("normal", forKey: "colormode")


        }

    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Normally gray text colors(User`s names and navigation title) must to be black in light mode, but they does not changed.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use a third-party library for this, it just complicates things. Use third parties for big things, like maps and databases, not run-of-the-mill things like color changes. To perform a color change during runtime, all you need to do is change the color of that object (or swap the image, etc.). To do that, I would recommend putting a notification listener in each view controller that listens for that toggle switch and when it is invoked, the handler of each listener (in each view controller) simply toggles the color of each view object in that view controller.

Comment: Notifications? They can be handled either by views or by controllers. No third-party library needed. Removing views from `window` and adding them again makes no sense and won't really help you.

Comment: I finally solved my issue with adding some modifications to pod, thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Use callback when `view mode` changes.
Change your colors as expected.

```swift
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    // do whatever you want to do 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out RxSwift and RxCocoa. They can both be found [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift). They are Reactive Frameworks for Reactive Programming in Swift. You can create observables to change the color of views reactively, as needed.

Comment: Or you can just use notifications. Adding Rx just for this is like killing a fly with a cannonball.

Comment: @Sulthan :D I think you`re right. I finally solved my issue with adding some modifications to pod, thanks again :)